# Removing Unnecessary Services & Packages in a MySQL Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: web-application, linux, php, databases, mysql

As part of hardening a MySQL 5.6 server running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, unnecessary services and packages will have to be removed.

For a server that is serving only as a MySQL server, what services and packages should we remove? Is there a list of services/packages that we can use?

Answer (score 1):

you're going the wrong way.

for debian-like systems the right way is:

- install a minimal system (e.g. from netinst)
- install the hardened-packages
- install wanted servers/applications

this assures to have only needed services and packages installed, no need to remove unwanted services like 10 years ago :)